# Point coordinates inside "add"

Tags: asymptote

I'm a begginner in asymptote.

I want to make a line(curve with arrow) from point B to point A that has more tension than normal (causing a smaller loop). I decided to create a function to calculate a point C that is between A and B, and then creating a path that passes in that point like so: B..C..A.

Using "dot" to draw the point I see it's well positioned.
But, using "dot" inside add(...) the point is positioned in a diferent place and so the (red) line.

What am I missing?

Here's the code and the image I get:

```
real u = 8cm;
unitsize(u);
real m = 3mm;

pair inbetween(pair a, pair b, real y)
{
    return ( (b.x - a.x)*0.5 + a.x, y );
}


pair pos3 = (3,0);
pair pos4 = (4,0);

object n3 = draw("n3",box,pos3,m);
object n4 = draw("n4",box,pos4,m);

pair p4_3 = inbetween(pos3, pos4, -1);
dot(p4_3);

add(new void(picture pic, transform t) {    
    path c = point(n4,E,t){SE}..{NE}point(n3,W,t);
    draw(pic, c, Arrow );

    dot(pic,p4_3,red);
    path c = point(n4,E,t){SE}..p4_3..{NE}point(n3,W,t);
    draw(pic, c, red, Arrow );
});
```

[image: Here's the output.]

Comment: Using "add" like this is a very advanced thing to be doing--you are basically dealing with undocumented Asymptote internals. Might I ask why "draw" will not suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not answer your question directly, but I think it offers an easier way to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish:

```
real u = 8cm;
unitsize(u);

real m = 3mm;

pair inbetween(pair a, pair b, real y)
{
    return ( (b.x - a.x)*0.5 + a.x, y );
}


pair pos3 = (3,0);
pair pos4 = (4,0);

// Using currentpicture.copy() preserves the size information.
picture n3=currentpicture.copy(), n4=currentpicture.copy();
draw(n3,"n3",box,pos3,m);
add(n3);
draw(n4,"n4",box,pos4,m);
add(n4);

pair p4_3 = inbetween(pos3, pos4, -1);
dot(p4_3);
pair a = truepoint(n4,E,user=true);
pair b = truepoint(n3,W,user=true);
draw(a{SE} .. p4_3 .. {NE}b, arrow=Arrow());
```

The result: (Note that the gigantic bounding box is fixed if you are willing to use `settings.outformat = "pdf";`.)

[image]

I would also note that there is an alternative built-in way to specify tension, although the results will not be identical to what you are doing:

```
settings.outformat="pdf";

real u = 8cm;
unitsize(u);

real m = 3mm;

pair pos3 = (3,0);
pair pos4 = (4,0);

// Using currentpicture.copy() preserves the size information.
picture n3=currentpicture.copy(), n4=currentpicture.copy();
draw(n3,"n3",box,pos3,m);
add(n3);
draw(n4,"n4",box,pos4,m);
add(n4);

pair a = truepoint(n4,E,user=true);
pair b = truepoint(n3,W,user=true);

//A more built-in way to handle tension:
int n = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
  real weight = i/n;
  pen thepen = weight*blue + (1-weight)*red;
  draw(a{SE} .. tension i .. {NE}b, p=thepen, arrow=Arrow(TeXHead));
}
```

[image]